# PropertiesInfo return Array with zero elemen

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have a class which have many list as attribute. When i using this code for get the PropertiesInfo it return array with zero element.

```
Type type = import.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance |BindingFlags.Public);
```

I have tried [this](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/c-reflection-list-t-t4035679.html) but i still have the same problem.

This is my class

```
public class ImportModel
{
    //REFERENSI
    //Level Area
    public List<LevelArea> lsLvlArea;

    //MASTER
    //Area
    public List<Area> lsArea;

    //Region
    public List<Customer> lsCustomer;

    //Branch
    public List<Product> lsProduct;

    //Distributor
    public List<Employee> lsEmployee;

    //Bank
    public List<Device> lsDevice;

    public ImportModel()
    {
        //Referensi
        lsLvlArea = new List<LevelArea>();

        //Master
        lsArea = new List<Area>();
        lsCustomer = new List<Customer>();
        lsDevice = new List<Device>();
        lsEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        lsProduct = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

I have googled it and not found a solution. Please help me.

Comment: Your class appears to have no properties - just member fields.

Comment: thanks i don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because none of these are properties, these are fields. You need to call

```
FieldInfo[] properties = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Alternatively, you can make your fields automatic properties:

```
public List<Device> lsDevice {get; set;}
```